# Hibernate 4 Generics: @Suppress Warnings vs Infer Generic Type Arguments?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I want to use generics in Java/Hibernate.

This is how some of the books that I've been studying have been doing it:

```
List messages = session.createQuery("from Message").list();
System.out.println("Found " + messages.size() + " message(s).");
```

I don't like that approach. I prefer using generics.

```
List<Message> messages = session.createQuery("from Message").list();
System.out.println("Found " + messages.size() + " message(s).");
```

But then again, I still get the "yellow" warning messages on my editor.

Eclipse recommends that I either suppress the warning by using @SuppressWarnings or infer generic type arguments. I'm not really sure what the latter means. But which one of the options is becoming the preferred approach to handling generics with Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Query#list()` unfortunately does return a raw list in Hibernate version 3.5.6-Final. This means, that you are not able to assign the result of this method to a variable of type `List<Message>` without a compiler warning. The only generic type you can assign the result to is `List<?>`. Eclipse just always suggests the infer type arguments option.

That being said, unlike Eclipse which always uses method scoping, I suggest the assignment scope SuppressWarnings annotation for clean code:

```
// Call to a raw method
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Message> messages = session.createQuery("from Message").list();
```